# How to add neo4j jdbc 2.3 with-dependencies.jar to maven

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, neo4j, dependencies

how to add the neo4j jdbc 2.3 with-dependencies.jar to my maven xml file. It looks like that at the moment

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

I get this console log after running my code

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
>       at jdbcNeo4j.Driver.main(Driver.java:103)

Comment: this is not available via standard maven repository I suppose ([here](https://maven-repository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-jdbc) I only see **2.1.4** as latest). The with-dependencies part is a fat jar generated as part of a build but not uploaded to a maven repository. Anyway, it's a `classifier`, so you would need to specify the classifier element in your `dependency` section (try adding `<classifier>with-dependencies</classifier>` to the snippet you provided)

Comment: it doesn't work with <classifier>with-dependencies</classifier> unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I usually include

```
 <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>neo4j-public</id>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/groups/public</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

The 2.3 snapshot is definitely available there https://m2.neo4j.org/content/groups/public/org/neo4j/neo4j-jdbc/2.3-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: which version is maven using when writing <id>neo4j-public</id> <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/groups/public</url>?